# customizing mail sending form in php using core php

Tags: php, mysql

Well i am in need of little help here.

I am doing a php custom mail sending form in which i need to make custom option for user to setup - port, host, smtp email, smtp pass, smtp username, also there is option to enable or disable smtp, Those all are working, but i have a situation here.

i also want to enable SSL Option for user, so if user select SSL is yes then it will send using SSL to prevent email going to SPAM. but i am unable to do this, can anyone help me with this.

here is code that i am using please check and assist anyone-

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m7ltrl8q0dxic4v/smtpmail-dummy.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here for this set the **SMTPSecure** property of **PHPMailer** class to 'ssl'. Then connect it using SmtpConnect() method.

So basically you can write a code like below. Not exactly, just for reference.

```
<?php
    $mail   = new PHPMailer; // call the class 
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->Host = SMTP_HOST; //Hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Port = SMTP_PORT; //Port of the SMTP like to be 25, 80, 465 or 587
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = SMTP_UNAME; //Username for SMTP authentication any valid email created in your domain
    $mail->Password = SMTP_PWORD; //Password for SMTP authentication
    $mail->AddReplyTo("developer@vrstamphead.com", "Developer Rakesh");
    //reply-to address
    $mail->SetFrom("developer@vrstamphead.com", "Developer Rakesh"); //From address of the mail
    // put your while loop here like below,
    $mail->Subject = "Your SMTP Mail"; //Subject od your mail
    $mail->AddAddress($email, "Asif18"); //To address who will receive this email
    $mail->MsgHTML("<b>Hi, your first SMTP mail has been received. Great Job!.. <br/><br/>by <a href='http://www.asif18.com/7/php/send-mails-using-smtp-in-php-by-gmail-server-or-own-domain-server/'>Asif18</a></b>"); //Put your body of the message you can place html code here

    if ($_SESSION['enable_ssl'] = 1) {    // 1 for true and 0 for false
        $mail->SMTPSecure = '';
        $mail->SmtpConnect();
    }

    $send = $mail->Send(); //Send the mails

    if($send){
        echo '<center><h3 style="color:#009933;">Mail sent successfully</h3></center>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<center><h3 style="color:#FF3300;">Mail error: </h3></center>'.$mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
?>
```

Instead of `$_SESSION['enable_ssl']`, you can use `$_POST['enable_ssl']` as well if you're providing it right a way.

Hope this helps...

Comment: sure, i will check it and will share my review. Hope that works!

Comment: Sure. Do accept the answer if it helps you have a solution. Its a "Tick" on the left when you click on it, it turns to green indicating the answer's accepted.

Comment: i checked but i am getting error- 

Mail error:

SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: Please check all the parameters that are pre-required for the $mail->SmtpConnect() method. For that please refer to the documentation that you obtained along with the Mailer library. You can find it on GitHub (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).